# Flickering gifs in java program

Tags: java, swing

I´m working on a program,where I have to insert some gifs to explain parts of the program. The first I´ve insert works fine. The next three I´ve used are flickering (the circles) when I put them in the program.
They are not flickering in image viewer.
I did the animation in After Effects, rendered as mov, imported in Photoshop and exported them as a gif. I´ve tried with dither and without. Background of the gifs has to be transparent.

I´m using same code for all the gifs. Also I insert the working gif on that place where the non-worikings should be used. On this place the good-gif works well too. So I guess no problem with my code.
This is how I insert them in the program:

```
JLabel gif = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gifs/soundcarpet.gif")));
gif.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
westPanel.add(gif, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

This is the working gif: [working gif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0m0Q0_2wdgkV3h4bUsyOU1uN0k)
This is one of the non-working ones: [not working](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0m0Q0_2wdgkMlpHZ05ULWJDVXc)

Can anybody figure out what the difference between them is?
I´ve made all of them with the same settings and I tried a lot of different ones for hours now...

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] in your question. You cannot expect people to surf to off-site resources to understand your problem. You can read more about asking questions on StackOverflow in the introductory [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 5):

If you split the GIF, you can see that the one you are having problems with is optimized with a technique that makes non-changing parts of each frame transparent (to reduce filesize).

You can open them in http://ezgif.com/split (select "Ignore optimizations" option) to see it yourself.

I don't really have experience with gifs in java, but I guess java can't handle this type of gif optimization. It's not surprising, as even specialized editors like imagemagick and gifsicle sometimes struggle with gifs like this and produce weird results (flickering, artifacts) on resizing or cropping.

You can upload the problematic gif on http://ezgif.com/optimize and select "Coalesce" option, or if you have ImageMagick installed, run the convert command with -coalesce option locally, it will redraw each frame completely removing this optimization and I think it will fix your problem. But it will increase file size of the gif.